# Can CartThrob send notification emails on wishlist/registry events?

Tags: cartthrob

We need to send a notification email to a person who receives an item from their registry.

- Person A: Adds item to registry
- Person B: Finds Person A's registry and purchases an item
- Person A: Receives a notification email informing them "An item has been purchased for you."

While this is one use case, are there any other wishlist/registry events that we can send notifications on?  I haven't been able to find any documentation on this and CartThrob seems to have a flexible notification architecture for steps in their other related CartThrob products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending an email to Person A from Person B is a completed feature that will be available in the next release of this add-on (along with a few bug fixes and template updates)

There are currently no other notification events though. If you think of any, feel free to post em, we'll add them to the feature request pile.

To answer your next question: The next release is complete. It'll be uploaded sometime in the next several days. Probably on Monday of this coming week.

Comment: You may have already done added this but would be nice to  have the ability to use Person A, Person B, and any items purchased in the email template.  Another notification event when a Registry is Created could be handy too.

Answer (score 0):

Chris, I would also be REALLY, very interested in the next release where we have it installed and working, but unable to share or email the wish lists. Is there an update for when the next version will be released?

Also I noticed that Wish Lists, as well as others addons, have been removed from the available products list on the website. Is this temporary?